# connecting spring cloud config server to local git repo failed

Tags: java, git, spring-boot

When I hit http://localhost:8888/limits-service/default I'm getting:

```
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Mon Apr 27 16:40:38 IST 2020
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
Cannot load environment
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load environment
    at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.JGitEnvironmentRepository.refresh(JGitEnvironmentRepository.java:299)
    at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.JGitEnvironmentRepository.getLocations(JGitEnvironmentRepository.java:246)
    at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.MultipleJGitEnvironmentRepository.getLocations(MultipleJGitEnvironmentRepository.java:146)
    at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.AbstractScmEnvironmentRepository.findOne(AbstractScmEnvironmentRepository.java:57)
    at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.MultipleJGitEnvironmentRepository.findOne(MultipleJGitEnvironmentRepository.java:187)
    at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.CompositeEnvironmentRepository.findOne(CompositeEnvironmentRepository.java:58)
    at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.EnvironmentEncryptorEnvironmentRepository.findOne(EnvironmentEncryptorEnvironmentRepository.java:61)
    at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.EnvironmentController.getEnvironment(EnvironmentController.java:136)
    at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.EnvironmentController.defaultLabel(EnvironmentController.java:108)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:282)
    at org.springframework.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope$LockedScopedProxyFactoryBean.invoke(GenericScope.java:499)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:691)
    at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.EnvironmentController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$61a7f28e.defaultLabel(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:105)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:879)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:793)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:109)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:373)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1594)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No directory at file:///C:lenovo G50git-localconfig-repo/limits-service.properties
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:73)
    at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.JGitEnvironmentRepository.copyFromLocalRepository(JGitEnvironmentRepository.java:576)
    at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.JGitEnvironmentRepository.copyRepository(JGitEnvironmentRepository.java:561)
    at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.JGitEnvironmentRepository.createGitClient(JGitEnvironmentRepository.java:547)
    at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.JGitEnvironmentRepository.refresh(JGitEnvironmentRepository.java:268)
    ... 72 more
```

This is my application.properties file:

```
spring.application.name=spring-cloud-config-server
server.port=8888
spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri=file:///C:\lenovo G50\git-localconfig-repo/limits-service.properties
```

This is the my local git repo file:

```
limits-service.minimum=8
limits-service.maximum=888
```

This is my main class:

```
package com.in28minutes.microservices.springcloudconfigserver;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.config.server.EnableConfigServer;

@EnableConfigServer
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringCloudConfigServerApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringCloudConfigServerApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Please help me to fix this.

Answer (score 2):

Replace application.properties:

```
spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri=file:///C:\lenovo G50\git-localconfig-repo/limits-service.properties
```

with

```
spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri=file://C:/lenovo G50/git-localconfig-repo
```

[image: Check out this configuration for your reference]

[image: check this output for your reference]

Comment: I think one of your pictures is broken. And please show textual information as text, not as (link to) picture of text.

Comment: Apart from the pictures of questionable helpfulness, what is the additional insight your post provides on top of the existing answers?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please make sure to read [answer] and swap the images you have posted for actual text. *Never, **ever*** post images of code or error messages. Also, as stated above, when your answer is already present, please refrain from posting it yet another time and up-vote helpful, correct answers instead. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The last entry in your stack trace shows an invalid resource location.

`java.lang.IllegalStateException: No directory at file:///C:lenovo G50git-localconfig-repo/limits-service.properties`

Since this is running within a JVM, you don't need to use backslashes in the path. In this instance, the backslashes are being used to escape the character immediately following the slash. Change the backslashes to forward slashes and that should get you past this error. This isn't directly related to getting a config server up and running, so no guarantees that this will fix all your problems.

Also, best to format your stack trace as code to make it more readable for other users.

Comment: getting same error after trying with your suggestion  (java.lang.IllegalStateException: No directory at file:\\\C:lenovo G50\git-localconfig-repo\limits-service.properties)  plz help me how to fix this

Comment: @Naga Please read more carefully, both the error messages and the answers you get: do not use backslashes, use forward slashes instead.

Comment: please help me for below question @Robert

Answer (score 1):

Remove all the backslashes from location path also and replace this with forward slash. Always remember to use `file://` before location path.

E.g.: `file://C:/Users/google/Desktop/SpringLearning/Mocroservice_new_June/git-localconfig-repo`

Try like this

Answer (score 0):

You should remove `file://` and try like this:

```
C:/lenovo G50/git-localconfig-repo/
```

Answer (score 0):

There should not be any space in the file names.

Remove the space, change the folder name from "lenovo G50" to "lenovo_G50" and is not required to point to the properties files that it picked up from URL which is been used.

Use below uri after removing the space:

```
spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri=C:/lenovo_G50/git-localconfig-repo
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope you would have gotten the answer by now.
Faced same problem myself. Figured the exception say

> No directory at file

that means you are not providing the directory instead providing the path to file:

```
file:///C:\lenovo G50\git-localconfig-repo/limits-service.properties
```

Just Remove the file from the path:

```
file:///C:\lenovo G50\git-localconfig-repo/
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

windows it says to put \ but I replaced it with / it works for me.
like

spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri=file:///D:\Programming\git-localconfig-repo

I got the same error I revert it and it works :)

server.port=8888

spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri=file:///D:/Programming/git-localconfig-repo

Answer (score 0):

#### This has nothing to do with java or spring framework,it completely depends on your os (development environment) -> Windows/Mac/Linux

For windows i used the path syntax as below & everything worked out perfectly:

```html
  
spring.application.name=spring-cloud-config-server
server.port=8888
spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri=E:\\__WORKSPACE__\\MICROSERVICES\\git-local-config
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are on windows make sure you are using the correct formats. These formats always work for me.

```
spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri=file:\\\C:/lenovo G50/git-localconfig-repo

spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri=file:///C:/lenovo G50/git-localconfig-repo
```

Hope this helps.